How to conditionally seriaize nested class with System.Text.Json?
I am looking to serialize a nested class on condition that value of an attribute is different than some custom value.
I was looking at: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-text-json-in-dotnet-7/#example:-conditional-serialization
But I need to modify this code to not serialize members of class inside a class.
Let say the custom value is "//".
public class MyPoco
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool IgnoreCustomValue { get; set; }

    public MyLittlePoco LPoco { get; set; }
}

public class MyLittlePoco
{
    public string DataOne { get; set; }
    public string DataTwo { get; set; }
}

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
    {
        Modifiers = { IgnoreNegativeValues }
    }
};

var LPocoNew = new MyLittlePoco { DataOne = "//"; DataTwo = "Hola";}

JsonSerializer.Serialize(new MyPoco { IgnoreCustomValue = true, LPoco = LPocoNew }, options); 


static void IgnoreNegativeValues(JsonTypeInfo typeInfo)
{
    if (typeInfo.Type != typeof(MyPoco))
        return;

    foreach (JsonPropertyInfo propertyInfo in typeInfo.Properties)
    {
        if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(MyLittlePoco ))
        {
           // Here I don't know how to proceed I would like to list through 
           // JsonPropertyInfo of MyLittlePoco and not serialize string attributes with value "//"
           
           propertyInfo.ShouldSerialize = static (obj, value) => 
                (string)value! == "//" || !((MyPoco)obj).IgnoreCustomValue ;
        }
    }
}



Firstly I don't know how to loop through nested class' JsonPropertyInfo.
And even if I knew how i am still not sure how to proceed.

Just to clarify, what you need is that, when serializing some large object graph, if a MyLittlePoco appears nested inside a MyPoco then its properties should be filtered out, but if it appears outside a MyPoco they should not be filtered out?  Or is your requirement that when serializing MyPoco as the root object the properties of MyLittlePoco should be filtered out?

If the latter (which is much simpler), why not just add the typeInfo modifier only if the root object is a MyPoco?  Is it because the call to JsonSerializer.Serialize() is made by the framework so you can't change it directly, you can only change it via modifying your JsonSerializerOptions?

Thanks, for the idea. Actually both option work for me. If MyLittlePoco appears outside or inside of MyPoco.
I will try to use typeInfo modifier to see if that can do what I want. Thanks.
